Unable to bypass rotate captcha using 2captcha API
I'm currently working on bypassing the rotate captcha on the 2captcha API's demo page. The issue I'm encountering isn't related to the integration aspect; I've already figured out how to integrate it with the 2captcha API. However, the challenge lies in correctly inserting the output, which in our case is '165 degrees,' into the appropriate place using JavaScript.
Upon closer analysis, I've observed that each right-click on the captcha image rotates it by 15 degrees and updates the 'style' attribute of the 'img' HTML tag accordingly. Therefore, by clicking the right button 11 times, we reach the desired 165-degree rotation, which successfully solves the captcha.
While my script effectively adds the rotation, ensuring the image appears correctly rotated, encountering a failure when clicking the 'check' button. Below is the snippet of the HTML:
<div class="_3i4YsKXQ1sT9uqskDtNNuA"><img src="/dist/web/43.png" alt="rotatecaptcha example" width="118" height="118" style="transform: rotate(165deg);"></div>
I've tried a lot of searches and unable to find any blog or tutorial for this kind of captcha, there are some other related question on stack but those are for simple captcha, like this one.
Here is the reproducible code:
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
import requests

# Initialize Chrome webdriver
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# option.add_argument("--headless")
option.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=option)

# Load the webpage
driver.get('https://2captcha.com/demo/rotatecaptcha')



image_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//img[@alt="rotatecaptcha example"]')
new_style = f"transform: rotate(165deg);"
driver.execute_script(f"arguments[0].setAttribute('style', '{new_style}')", image_element)

sleep(3)

try:
    click_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@type="submit"]').click(); sleep(15)
except:
    print('Not able to locate the click button')


always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

maybe first run without try/except to see FULL error message

changing style can't resolve captcha because it may keep this information in some variable in JavaScript. It may need to click button with arrow.

@furas, the problem is that there is no error message as the script works as expected, it injects 165 degree and i can see that the image is rotating to the right degree, but when click the button it says, captcha fails to resolve

You can't resolve it by changing style because probably it checks some variable in JavaScript which is changed when user presses button with arrow.
You have to click right arrow 11 times.
arrow = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[contains(@class, "rotateRight")]')
for _ in range(11):
    arrow.click()


Full working code - tested with Firefox (and later with Chrome)
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

#from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep

#option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
# option.add_argument("--headless")
option.add_argument("--start-maximized")
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=option)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()), options=option)

driver.get('https://2captcha.com/demo/rotatecaptcha')

sleep(1)

arrow = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[contains(@class, "rotateRight")]')
for _ in range(11):
    arrow.click()

try:
    button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@type="submit"]')
    button.click()
    sleep(15)
    #input('Press ENTER to close')
except:
    print('Not able to locate the click button')


if we can do it like that, then may I know the purpose of 2captcha api? as i already know that i have to rotate it 165 degree,  does this captcha change for each user? or each time the user navigate to the website?

this page is only DEMO. Real page may show different image with different rotation and it may need to use machine learning to correctly rotate it. And maybe 2captcha has already tool to work with any image and any rotation.
